# Don`t give Daily Summaries from Garmin Api

Tags: php, curl, iot, healthkit, garmin

I wanna  get "Daily Summaries" for my devices through garmin API.

I can get data form https://healthapi.garmin.com/ , but can`t through api request.

For obtain "Daily Summaries", I do the following steps:

I create curl command:

`curl -v -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf-8" -d '{"dailies":[{"userAccessToken":"userAccessToken","uploadStartTimeInSeconds":1514847600,"uploadEndTimeInSeconds":1515597660,"callbackURL":" https://healthapi.garmin.com/wellnessapi/rest/dailies"}]}' http://mysite/testping.php`

Where userAccessToken - is tocken which i use to login in https://healthapi.garmin.com/  . in response i get request without any data.

i use manual "Health REST API Specification" as example.

Please answer, why i don`t give any data from request?

Comment: How you get the useraccesstoken via the API @Pavel

Comment: if you are getting empty array.(like: [ ]) then change your uploadStartTimeInSeconds and uploadEndTimeInSeconds. But if garmin user's profile contain no activities then it will return empty array in response.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems.  The request, if it were made directly to Garmin's API server, needs to be signed (OAuth1) and according to the HealthAPI docs, it is a GET, not a POST.

Most importantly, the CURL request goes to a local PHP server, not to Garmin.  I have no idea of what's running at that server, so there's no way to debug this further.  The Garmin address is in the JSON data payload, but curl is POSTing this payload to http://mysite/testping.php

I would suggest starting by sending requests directly to the Garmin API server, if possible, using a tool like Postman to make sure that the request is correctly formed, signed for OAuth v1, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The backfill sets a trigger to push new historical data to you end point.

Quote from Garmin's Health API Specification Document -  Section 8:

"A backfill request returns an empty response immediately, while the actual backfill process takes place asynchronously in the background. Once backfill is complete, a notification will be generated and sent as if data for that time period was newly-synced. Both the Ping Service and the Push Service are supported by Summary Backfill. The maximum date range (inclusive) for a single backfill request is 90 days, but it is permissible to send multiple requests representing other 90 day periods to retrieve additional data."